# Calculating travel statistics based on CSV data

Tags: python, beginner, interview-questions, csv

I took a code test for acme transport company and was rejected. That's ok. I'm still learning how to code. I didn't get much feedback so that's a bit frustrating. Can anyone here provide tips on how to optimize this python code? I thought that I had done a pretty good job with it, had the correct answers, etc. But apparently there are some fatal flaws, at least according to acme transport co!

Here's the challenge:

Parse a [text file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pepebutter/f840e635d0d063ce7e1b744023b09ce8/raw/50e388ae1164598299b9700c1eff22be049ee19f/events.txt) so that we know the following:

- how many cars were dropped in total?
- which car had the longest single trip? How long was the trip?
- what car had the longest cumulative distance? How long was that.

The text file is formatted like this:

- timestamp, Integer, The time in seconds since the start of the simulation
- id, String, The id of the associated vehicle, e.g. JK5T
- event_type, String The type of the event is one of START_RIDE, END_RIDE, DROP
- x, Double, The x coordinate of the location of where the event happened in the simulation
- y, Double, The y coordinate of the location of where the event happened in the simulation
- user_id, Integer, The id of the associated user or NULL if the event does not have an associated user

The first few lines of the file look like this:

```
302,OPN1,DROP,33.28280226855614,-87.88162047789511,NULL
305,OPN1,START_RIDE,33.28280226855614,-87.88162047789511,4204
419,G2I0,DROP,-28.367411419413685,23.567421582328606,NULL
426,OPN1,END_RIDE,7.563016232237587,91.97004351346015,4204
428,LQBF,DROP,-50.50579634246066,-54.53980771216895,NULL
441,5HQH,DROP,-70.05156581770649,36.8358644984674,NULL
```

For my code I import a library called shapely that helps determine distances:

```
import csv
from shapely.geometry import Point
from collections import defaultdict



def main():
        myDict = defaultdict(dict)
        aDict = {}
        totalDrops = 0
        maxCar = None
        with open('events.txt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[2] == 'DROP':
                    totalDrops += 1 
                    myDict[row[1]]['drop'] = Point(float(row[3]), float(row[4]))
                if row[2] == 'START_RIDE':
                    myDict[row[1]]['start_ride'] = Point(float(row[3]), float(row[4]))
                if row[2] == 'END_RIDE':
                    singleTripDistance = myDict[row[1]]['drop'].distance(Point(float(row[3]), float(row[4])))
                    distanceTraveled = myDict[row[1]]['start_ride'].distance(Point(float(row[3]), float(row[4])))
                    aDict[row[1]] = singleTripDistance
                    if not maxCar:
                        maxCar = row[1]
                    if 'allDistances' not in myDict[row[1]]:
                        myDict[row[1]]['allDistances'] = distanceTraveled
                    else:
                        myDict[row[1]]['allDistances'] += distanceTraveled
                    if  myDict[row[1]]['allDistances'] > myDict[maxCar]['allDistances']:
                        maxCar = row[1]
            maxSingleTrip = max(zip(aDict.values(), aDict.keys()))
            print('There are ' + '' + str(totalDrops) + ' ' + 'total Drops.' + '\n' + 'The Car that ends up furthest away from its drop is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[1]) + ' ' + 'and the distance is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[0]) + '\n' + 'The Car with the highest total distance traveled is:' + ' ' + maxCar + ', ' + 'and the total distance is:' + ' ' +  str(myDict[maxCar]['allDistances']))
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

### What you did well

You used the `csv` module for parsing the CSV file, and you processed it in one pass.  Your code is therefore reasonably efficient, and I wouldn't worry much about its performance.

### Bugs

Your code reports "The Car that ends up furthest away from its drop is: …", but that is, in my interpretation, not the same as the longest single trip, which is what you were asked to calculate.

### Concerns

Your **data analysis code is mingled with the CSV parsing**.  That makes the code hard to read and hard to maintain.

The **deeply nested dictionaries** are hard to understand.  What does `myDict` store?  Its purpose is not apparent from its name.  It's a two-level dictionary, where the first-level key is a `vehicle_id`, the second-level key is some attribute of that vehicle (the `'drop'` coordinate, the `'start_ride'` coordinate, or the `'allDistances'` running total).  You would be better off with three independent dictionaries.  Better yet, as I've done below, define an `Itinerary` class instead.

What's `aDict`?  It keeps track of the distance from each car's drop point to the endpoint of its last trip.  Again, the **variable name does not help**.

**The `print()` call is hard to read**, in an excessively long line of code, with lots of `str()` casts and unnecessary string concatenations.  In this situation, I would recommend [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) (introduced in Python 3.6), or [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

### Suggested solution

This solution reports the car that ends up the furthest from its drop point, as you did, rather than the longest single trip as requested.

The Shapely library is overkill; subclassing [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with a `.distance()` method is all I need for a handy `Point` class.  Euclidean distances can be calculated using [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot).

If you look at the data, you'll see that each car acts as a state machine.  It is initialized with a `DROP` event.  Thereafter, it alternates between `START_RIDE` and `END_RIDE` events.  No traveling is allowed when a `START_RIDE` occurs; the car is always the same place as its preceding `DROP` or `END_RIDE` coordinates.  In my `Itinerary` class, I've kept track of the `.state` of the car so that I can perform certain assertions, but it's only essential to keep track of the coordinates at each `DROP` and `END_RIDE` event.

The `itineraries()` function parses the CSV into one simple data structure: a dictionary mapping vehicle IDs to their itineraries.  I've chosen to use [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) to accept the file on the command line or through `sys.stdin` without hard-coding the filename.

The data analysis is accomplished using [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) `len()` and `max()` with [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).  That is more expressive and less cumbersome than maintaining several intermediate results each time an `END_RIDE` event occurs.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
import fileinput
from math import hypot
from operator import attrgetter

class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y')):
    def distance(self, other):
        """Euclidean distance between two points."""
        return hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

class Itinerary:
    def __init__(self, car, x, y):
        self.car = car
        self.coords = [Point(x, y)]
        self.state = 'DROP'
        self.cumul_dist = 0

    def start_ride(self, x, y):
        assert self.state in ('DROP', 'END_RIDE'), "Restarting unfinished ride"
        assert Point(x, y) == self.coords[-1], "Teleportation occurred"
        self.state = 'START_RIDE'

    def end_ride(self, x, y):
        assert self.state == 'START_RIDE', "Ending a ride that hasn't started"
        self.coords.append(Point(x, y))
        self.state = 'END_RIDE'
        self.cumul_dist += self.coords[-1].distance(self.coords[-2])

    @property
    def final_dist(self):
        return self.coords[-1].distance(self.coords[0])

def itineraries(f):
    cars = {}
    for timestamp, car, event_id, x, y, user_id in csv.reader(f):
        if event_id == 'DROP':
            assert car not in cars, "Dropping the same car twice"
            cars[car] = Itinerary(car, float(x), float(y))
        elif event_id == 'START_RIDE':
            cars[car].start_ride(float(x), float(y))
        elif event_id == 'END_RIDE':
            cars[car].end_ride(float(x), float(y))
    return cars

def main():
    cars = itineraries(fileinput.input()).values()
    drops = len(cars)
    furthest = max(cars, key=attrgetter('final_dist'))
    most_traveled = max(cars, key=attrgetter('cumul_dist'))
    print(f"""There are {drops} total drops.
The car that ends up furthest from its drop is {furthest.car}, at distance {furthest.final_dist}.
Car {most_traveled.car} travels the longest cumulative distance: {most_traveled.cumul_dist}.""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hm, fair enough. Apparently I can't even read today...

Answer (score 2):

**Making the code easier to read with variables**

Having all the accesses to `row[something]` everywhere makes the code hard to read and to update.
A good idea could be to introduce variables with meaningful names. You'd get for instance `x = row[3]`.

Also Python offers a concise way to do this: iterable unpacking.

In your case, you could write something like:

```
        timestamp, vehicle_id, event, x, y, user_id = row
```

And by using these variables instead of accessing `row`, your code is already much prettier (and may be slighly faster as well).

We could go further and also define:

```
        coord = Point(float(x), float(y))
```

**Use `if/else` for mutually exclusive conditions**

You check `if event == 'DROP'` then `if event == 'START_RIDE'`. Of course, at most one of these can be true. I can be a good habit to use `elif` in this case. Also, you can take this chance to add a case to handle unknown events.

```
def main():
    myDict = defaultdict(dict)
    aDict = {}
    totalDrops = 0
    maxCar = None
    with open('events.txt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            timestamp, vehicle_id, event, x, y, user_id = row
            coord = Point(float(x), float(y))
            if event == 'DROP':
                totalDrops += 1 
                myDict[vehicle_id]['drop'] = coord 
            elif event == 'START_RIDE':
                myDict[vehicle_id]['start_ride'] = coord
            elif event == 'END_RIDE':
                singleTripDistance = myDict[vehicle_id]['drop'].distance(coord)
                distanceTraveled = myDict[vehicle_id]['start_ride'].distance(coord)
                aDict[vehicle_id] = singleTripDistance
                if not maxCar:
                    maxCar = vehicle_id
                if 'allDistances' not in myDict[vehicle_id]:
                    myDict[vehicle_id]['allDistances'] = distanceTraveled
                else:
                    myDict[vehicle_id]['allDistances'] += distanceTraveled
                if  myDict[vehicle_id]['allDistances'] > myDict[maxCar]['allDistances']:
                    maxCar = vehicle_id
            else:
                print("Unexpected event ", e)
        maxSingleTrip = max(zip(aDict.values(), aDict.keys()))
        print('There are ' + '' + str(totalDrops) + ' ' + 'total Drops.' + '\n' + 'The Car that ends up furthest away from its drop is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[1]) + ' ' + 'and the distance is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[0]) + '\n' + 'The Car with the highest total distance traveled is:' + ' ' + maxCar + ', ' + 'and the total distance is:' + ' ' +  str(myDict[maxCar]['allDistances']))
main()
```

**Non-required dependency**

You've used an external dependency to handle the logic computing the distance.

It is good to avoid the [Not Invented Here syndrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) and avoid [re-inventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

On the other hand, dependencies on external packages are sometimes undesirable because of the amount of code you are using/integrating with no or little knowledge about.

I do not know what was the point of view of the staff reviewing your code but **maybe** they'd have appreciated if you had defined a simple class like:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self, other):
        dx = self.x - other.x
        dy = self.y - other.y
        return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Add a bit of doc and/or tests and it makes for a first good impression.

**Variable names**

`myDict` is not a great variable names as it does not convey much meanings. Maybe `vehicles` would be better or `vehicles_dict`...

Also, there is a style guide in Python called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is a highly recommended read. Among other things, it advices to use `snake_case` for variable names (instead of `camelCase`).

**More variables**

It may be worth defining yet another variable to make the code more concise:

```
        vehicle = vehicles[vehicle_id]
```

Then, we'd have something like:

```
def main():
    vehicles = defaultdict(dict)
    aDict = {}
    total_drops = 0
    max_car = None
    with open('events.txt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            timestamp, vehicle_id, event, x, y, user_id = row
            coord = Point(float(x), float(y))
            vehicle = vehicles[vehicle_id]
            if event == 'DROP':
                total_drops += 1 
                vehicle['drop'] = coord 
            elif event == 'START_RIDE':
                vehicle['start_ride'] = coord
            elif event == 'END_RIDE':
                singleTripDistance = vehicle['drop'].distance(coord)
                distanceTraveled = vehicle['start_ride'].distance(coord)
                aDict[vehicle_id] = singleTripDistance
                if not max_car:
                    max_car = vehicle_id
                if 'allDistances' not in vehicle:
                    vehicle['allDistances'] = distanceTraveled
                else:
                    vehicle['allDistances'] += distanceTraveled
                if  vehicle['allDistances'] > vehicles[max_car]['allDistances']:
                    max_car = vehicle_id
            else:
                print("Unexpected event ", e)
        maxSingleTrip = max(zip(aDict.values(), aDict.keys()))
        print('There are ' + '' + str(total_drops) + ' ' + 'total Drops.' + '\n' + 'The Car that ends up furthest away from its drop is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[1]) + ' ' + 'and the distance is:' + ' ' + str(maxSingleTrip[0]) + '\n' + 'The Car with the highest total distance traveled is:' + ' ' + max_car + ', ' + 'and the total distance is:' + ' ' +  str(vehicles[max_car]['allDistances']))
main()
```

**Data structure**

From the way the problem is stated, it looks like the staff was interested in seeing which data structure you'd use and how.

Defining a dictionnary mapping vehicles identifiers to other data is definitly good into the right directions.

*I may stop this review at any time. Don't be surprised if it looks unfinished, I may try to get back to this later.*